# Button is not getting clicked using Robot framework with playwright library

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, playwright

I am using Robot Framework with Playwright library. I am having some issue when clicking on Save/Spara button inside a tbody. Other button is getting clicked just fine but having issue only with this one.

When i use css and text selectors i am getting a console error message after timeout “TimeoutError: locator.click: Timeout 10000ms exceeded.”
And when i use absolute xpath i get console error message “Unexpected token “/” while parsing selector”.
I also realised that the focus from a previous element was not moving onto this button so i specifically introduced Tab key in my script and now the focus is on Button but its still not getting clicked.

I have tried following locator:

Click      xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-success"]

Click      button[data-bind=“click: $root.SparaAllaVaccinationer, visible: $root.SparaVaccinationEnabled($data)”] i[class=‘fa fa-2x fa-save’]

Click      button[title=“Spara”]

Click      //button[contains(@title,‘Spara’)]

Press Keys    xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-success"]    Enter
When i used Press Keys, before this i had already moved the focus onto this button. But i got same console error.

Here is the element i am trying to click:

```
<button title="Spara" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $root.SparaAllaVaccinationer, visible: $root.SparaVaccinationEnabled($data)" style="">
                            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-save"></i><br><span class="small">Spara</span>
                        </button>
```

Has anyone faced similar issue ?

Comment: I have also referred following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413009/click-element-in-robot-framework-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by using:

Press Keys    xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-success" and contains(text(),'Spara')]    Enter

But i would really appreciate if someone can explain why it was not working with simple Click action  with class in xpath
Click xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-success"]
OR
Press Keys xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-success"] Enter